# How to create a counter with a loop that iterates and adds 22 to an initial number every 7 days?

Tags: javascript, php, cron, counter

I'm looking for a solution to make a counter that would iterate ands 22 to an initial number every 7 days.

Anyone have an idea?

I'm a beginner PHP developer and I doubt this is enough.

I think in particular that it will be necessary to trigger CRON tasks to restart the script each time, but how to save the previous number and iterate it by 22 every 7 days?

I tried this script below during my tests but quickly realized that it had to be done differently.

```
$myarr=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
foreach($myarr as $p){
//print out a number and then pause for two seconds
    ob_start();
    echo "$p <br/>";
    $size = ob_get_length();
    ob_end_flush();
    @ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: If you run a script multiple times which your inital solution with using cron does you need to save the value outside of memory as that will be destroyed on every execution. You need to look into probably writing to file with that solution (you could also use a database but seems extremly overkill in this situation) 

There also depending a bit on exact limitations to solve this problem without needing to run the same script multiple times (but thoose also have disadvantages)

Comment: If you just want to add 22 to a given starting value every 7 days, then you don't need a cron job, you can simply _calculate_ what the value at a certain date X would be - by getting the number of weeks between your starting date, and date X - and then you add 22 times that number, to your starting value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer which will help me @Virré and thank you for this excellent suggestion @C Bro, it allows me to better understand to start on a good basis!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.